# Determine whether a file is a binary executable file or a script file using gcc in Linux

Tags: c, linux, header, elf

In Linux both a binary executable file and a script can be marked "executable". I would like to determine in my gcc program whether the file is a script or a binary executable.

I read that there is an a.out.h file which allows to analyse the header of the file but I do not know how to use this in my code. Or if there is a simple solution instead.

Comment: man access will tell you if it's executable. Reading some number of bytes will tell if it's ascii or binary. man magic might be of interest too.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "gcc program".  You may mean a "C program" that you compiled with GCC.

Comment: Consider whether you really need to do this. The whole point of scripts is that they can be executed as if they were binary executable programs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check so-called magic bytes. For elf 1st four bytes are supposed to be `7f 45 4c 46` in hex. You have to care for byte order though.

Opening file in binary mode and reading 1st four bytes should suffice.

E.g.

```
shell$ hexdump -n 10 ./ni6_ga
0000000 457f 464c 0101 0301 0000
```

Comment: Whereas a script will start with `#!`

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: Not necessarily. An executable text file that doesn't start with `#!` is treated as a `/bin/sh` script. (Retroactively following up to your followup, it's certainly good practice to use the `#!` anyway.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Indeed. I forgot about that (as I think it is "good practice" to include the she-bang, regardless).

Comment: I usually write my shell scripts without #! and they run fine. So to check for that seems to be not reliable.

The a.out.h file has a NMAGIC() macro to check the magic bytes. Has anyone used that yet? (And maybe has an example for that?)

Comment: The macros I mentioned refer to the older a.out executable format. For the common ELF format luk32's answer is correct and sufficient.

Comment: Thank you very much and also thank you too for Keith, Jonathon and Charlie